# Github action fails for build and deploy on Fetch API

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using this GitHub action https://github.com/JamesIves/fetch-api-data-action  to fetch and save data fetched by an API:

this is my configuration for 2 actions, one to fetch the API and then build and deploy to save the .json fetching from the API

```
name: Refresh Feed
on: [push]
jobs:
  refresh-feed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetch API Data 
        uses: JamesIves/fetch-api-data-action@releases/v1
        with:
          ENDPOINT: https://data
          BRANCH: master # Pushes the updates to the master branch.


      - name: Build and Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
        with:
          branch: master # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: . # The folder the action should deploy.
```

it fails with this error

```
Run JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
9

10
    GitHub Pages Deploy Action 
11

12
     Getting Started Guide: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages
13
    ❓ Discussions / Q&A: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/discussions
14
     Report a Bug: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/issues
15

16
     Maintained by James Ives: https://jamesiv.es
17
     Support: https://github.com/sponsors/JamesIves
18
Checking configuration and starting deployment… 
19
Deploying using Deploy Token… 
20
Configuring git…
21
/usr/bin/git config user.name abcname
22
fatal: not in a git directory
23
Error: There was an error initializing the repository: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128 ❌
24
Deployment failed! ❌
```

I tried also "public" as folder but it fails too as it says it doesn't exist (my repo does have that folder though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of that action. Perhaps try moving to v4 which handles some of these parameters differently. If you are pushing back to the same repository you do not even need to pass a token.

Other than that, I see two possible things to check:

1. You reference branch `main` in the first action but `master` in the second. Are these pointing to the same repository? If so, I'd think the branch names would be the same.
2. With the v3 component, the docs for `ACCESS_TOKEN` kind of imply you need to be using a generated Personal Access Token that you have stored in the secrets. That is what I used when using this action although I was pushing to a different repository so the was a must anyway.

I moved to v4 quite a while ago though.

Comment: I upgraded to vs 4 for the deploy but now I am getting Configuring git…
21
/usr/bin/git config user.name name
22
fatal: not in a git directory
23
Error: There was an error initializing the repository: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128 ❌
24
Deployment failed! ❌ this is my action now  - name: Build and Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
        with:
          branch: master # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: . # The folder the action should deploy.  I tried also "public" as folder but it says it doesn't exis

Comment: I think the problem is that you are missing the checkout step.

      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1